# Set different mail ID than domain in postfix

Tags: postfix

I have installed postfix in my ubuntu server. My domain name is `www.mydomain.com` and I want to configure postfix with different mail ID and with different domain, like `mail@differentdomain.com` instead of `mail@mydomain.com`

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: check this link, http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_mailbox

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. For that you need to create virtual domain. Follow these steps:

- Edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

  ```
  mydestination = differentdomain.com 
  virtual_alias_domains = differentdomain.com 
  virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
  virtual_mailbox_domains = differentdomain.com
  virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
  ```
- Update `/etc/postfix/virtual` file

  ```
  mail@differentdomain.com mail
  ```
- Update `/etc/postfix/vmailbox` file

  ```
  mail@differentdomain.com      differentdomain.com/mail
  ```
- After changing the virtual file execute this command `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual`
- After changing the vmailbox file execute this command `postmap /etc/postfix/vmailbox`
- After changing the main.cf file execute this command `postfix reload` or restart the postfix service by execute this command `sudo service postfix restart`

Comment: Ok. I will try it.

Comment: Is it working? @Akshay

Comment: Actually that server is Live, so I'm not able to test it. I had to use different solution for the time being. I will definitely try this method sometime. But right now I'm not able to do it. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Share your solution man. @Akshay

Comment: I was facing the problem of mails in Drupal system. So I installed a module [SMTP Authentication Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) for it. So, the mails are working well with this thing.